# What is the difference between both types of instatiation of inner static class

Tags: java

I am working with static inner class and I see we can instantiate the object `Pc` like these can I get the difference and when to use which?

```
public class ProducerConsumer {


    public static void main(String [] args){
     PC pc = new PC(); // this
     ProducerConsumer.PC pc1 = new ProducerConsumer.PC(); // and this

    }

    static class PC {

    }
}
```

Comment: The second is redundant, that's the only difference in this case.

Comment: I think you need to check nested classes topic,https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: There is no such thing as a "static inner class". An inner class is *by definition* not static - it's another name for a non-static member class.

Comment: Never use the phrase _"static inner class"_ with respect to Java - it's self-contradicting, as Erwin pointed out in the previous comment. Instead, refer to a _"static nested class"_. Ironically, the worst source on the internet for propagating the concept of a **_static inner class_** in Java is StackOverflow, [through  questions, and answers which fail to refute the concept](http://symbolhound.com/?q=&l=&e=static+inner+class&n=&u=)!

Answer (score 1):

There are no difference between these statements:

1. `PC pc = new PC()`
2. `ProducerConsumer.PC pc1 = new ProducerConsumer.PC();`

You can use both variants. Moreover, you can use variant 1 in other class, but in that case you have to add static import to the `ProducerConsumer`.

**NO DIFFERENCE.**